# -[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: message sent to deallocated

Tags: iphone

I am working on an iphone app, in which to count the number of days between two dates I am using the code as follows:

```
    double intevalInSeconds = [selectedDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:newfromdate];
int dayInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
int day = intevalInSeconds / dayInSeconds;
NSLog(@"counted days are:%d",day);
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:     
    NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *days = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSInteger dayCount = 0;
while ( TRUE ) {
    [days setDay: ++dayCount];
    NSDate *date = [gregorianCalendar dateByAddingComponents: days toDate: newfromdate 
            options: 0];
    if ( [date compare: selectedDate2] == NSOrderedDescending )
        break;
    NSString *dateForAdd=[df stringFromDate:date];
    [countdays addObject:dateForAdd];
}
NSLog(@"daysdetail:%@",countdays);
appendarray = countdays;
NSLog(@"append array is:%@",appendarray);
}
```

When i run this app on simulator it is working fine but whenever I tried to run it on device it is giving the error|:- [__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x65a30b0

Please tell me if I doing some wrong in the above code.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Where you are creating `selectedDate2` and are you retaining it? If `selectedDate2` is created outside the current method, you should retain it.

Comment: You are not calling that method.. Where you are getting the crash exactly, means which line?

Answer (score 0):

`timeIntervalSinceDate:` calls `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`.

So your code seems to be deallocating one of the NSDates somewhere before the code you are showing us.